# Hbase can not start

Tags: hbase

I am referring  the [link](https://www.datageekinme.com/setup/setting-up-my-mac-hbase/) to install `hbase` on mac.

but when starting `hbase` error occur

> error-: mkdir: /log: Permission denied starting regionserver, logging
>   to /log/hbase-evioxtech-1-regionserver-evioxs-mac-mini.lan.out
>   /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.3.4/libexec/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 189:
>   /log/hbase-evioxtech-1-regionserver-evioxs-mac-mini.lan.out: No such
>   file or directory head:
>   /log/hbase-evioxtech-1-regionserver-evioxs-mac-mini.lan.out: No such
>   file or directory

how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'd guess the `/log` is coming from this line: `export HBASE_LOG_DIR=$HBASE_HOME/logs`. Do you have a typo in this line? Have you somehow stopped exporting `HBASE_HOME`?

Comment: No I can't stop stopped exporting HBASE_HOME

Comment: Can you look at line 189 of /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.3.4/libexec/bin/hbase-daemon.sh then and work out where it's getting the string "/log/hbase-evioxtech-1-regionserver-evioxs-mac-mini.lan.out" from? Because it probably shouldn't start with a bare /log.

Comment: Now error is :-Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase